# Excel Multiple Criteria Function with Between

Tags: excel, if-statement, lookup

So I have a cell with the following information, for example "Score 8/10" and I need a formula that translates to "if the value is between 0 and 4, return "Bad", if the value is between 5 and 7, return "Medium", if the value is between 8 and 10, return "Good".

I tried a If with a mid to extract the "8" from the "Score 8/10", but couldn't manage to get the rest of the result.

Comment: A piece of advise : in such a case, create two columns: one containing the obtained result, next with the maximum result (you can always create a third column, concatenating both results with a "/" in between), it will be far easier to handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
=CHOOSE(MATCH(1*TRIM(MID(A1,FIND("/",A1)-2,2)),{0,5,8}),"Bad","Medium","Good")
```

Comment: Instead of `CHOOSE/MATCH` lookup can be used `=LOOKUP(1*TRIM(MID(A1,FIND("/",A1)-2,2)),{0,5,8},{"Bad","Medium","Good"})`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer, although I think @pnut's is preferable.

```
=IF(MID(A3,(FIND(" ",A3,1)+1),FIND("/",A3,(FIND(" ",A3,1)+1))-(FIND(" ",A3,1)+1))+0<5,"Bad", IF(MID(A3,(FIND(" ",A3,1)+1),FIND("/",A3,(FIND(" ",A3,1)+1))-(FIND(" ",A3,1)+1))+0>7, "Good","Medium"))
```

This gets the characters between the first space character and the first "/" character, converts them to a number and then compares than number to select an appropriate value.